# release an object, memory management, Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

If I have
ClassA.h

> 1.@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray    *arr;

ClassA.m

> -(ClassA) function {
>
> ```
>     1.ClassA *obj = [[ClassA alloc] init]; 
>     // initialize the arr
>     // add another object into the arr
>     2. [obj.arr addObject:nameOfAnObject]
>     3. return obj;
> ```
>
> }

at ClassB, I want to call **(ClassA) function** method.What I do is

ClassB.m

> -(void)viewDidload {
>
> ```
>   1.[super viewDidLoad];
>   2.ClassA     *classAinB = [[classA alloc] init];                                                                        
>   3.classAinB = [classA function];
>   4.[classAinB release];
> ```
>
> }

According the rule of memory management,because I own a **ClassAinB** in ClassB.m, so I free it at the end.

My question is how is the var **ClassA** which I own in ClassA.m, when should I release it so that after a call back at line 3 of ClassB, I still have the object of ClassA whose arr is containing **nameOfAnObject** object

Please advice me on this issue. Any comments are welcomed here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to the autorelease pool. i.e. `return [obj autorelease];`. This will make sure the object is sent a `release` message at the end of the run loop iteration if it no longer has any owner.

Comment: how id about :ClassA *obj = [[[ClassA alloc] init] autorelease];. Is it the meaning as return [ [obj autorelease] ];

Comment: you can do that too. It does the same thing since it's all done within the same run loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you have an `alloc` you need a corresponding `release` to match it.

In XCode 4.2 + with the LLMV compiler (and ARC enabled) you don't have to worry about reference counting, so when you `alloc` an object, you don't need to worry about calling `release`, in fact you can't, as the compiler will throw an error.

Comment: i think you mean if you have ARC enabled, not ios5+

Comment: I've modified my response to be more correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you use manual retain-release:
You allocate 2 objects of classA. One - when you directly allocate it from classB function, another - when you calls classA function inside that function. So, when line 3 performs, you destroys link (overwrite classAinB var) on first classA object and this is a memory leak.
If you wish use factory method that returns you an object of classA, make that method static.